# Jquery tooltip information

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created textarea in which description will be entered by user. I have created tooltip for this textarea. When user types in textarea, he has to see simultaneously what he is typing in tootip. Could anyone suggest how it can be achieved using js or jquery.

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far? You should show us the code in a JSFiddle or JSBin, and detail your requirements more.

Comment: This is a really unusual thing to want to achieve! Why do you want to see the typed text in a tooltip AND the textarea?!

Comment: Hi, my text area is small. So if user enters huge comment he has to scroll up to see the top content.

Comment: Hi Bagavatu,   Since i posted it from my phone, i am not able to share the code. Will share it in some time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Say your [`textarea` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html) has [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) `foo`. And whatever the element you're using as tooltip has id `bar`.

```
$('#foo').on('keyup', function () {
    // When the user writes in to the textarea
    // asign textarea's text to tooltip
    $('#bar').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hi thats worked perfectly.. I tried on change function thats y not worked. Thanks for your help.